# When does the limit of an arithmetic mean sequence exists?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $(a_n)_{n\ge 1}$ be a real sequence and $b_n = \dfrac{a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n}{n}$.

It's known that, if $\lim a_n$ exists, then $\lim b_n$ exists and is equal to $\lim a_n$.

However, $\lim b_n$ might exist even if $\lim a_n$ doesn't. So my question is: When does $\lim b_n$ exists?

For instance, does $b_n$ has a limit whenever $a_n$ is limited?

Comment: Does $\lim b_n$ exist whenever $ is $bounded.  No.  See if you can find a sequence of $1$s and $0$s for $a_n$, where $b_n$ does not converge.

Comment: Meanwhile, there are also unbounded sequences $(a_n)_n$ for which $(b_n)_n$ converges. For example, a sequence with a subsequence that goes to infinity but with so many $0$s around them that the non-zero terms get "drowned" in those due to the averaging.

Comment: Maybe check out [Cesàro summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation)?